# chapter heading prevent hyphenation or overflow

Tags: sectioning, hyphenation, overflow

In the example below i want the chapter headings to not hyphenate but to be on the next line.

I have tried multiple solutions i found on TexExchange.  These do not seem to work for my example.

Setting `\mbox` or something else manually is not possible.

## Update:

@Ivan solved this in the comments.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{microtype}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
}
\newgeometry{left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=50mm, top=25mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
% Because the report class defines pagestyle plain, but we use the fancy page style
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

%Font
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0cm}{0cm}{5mm}[15mm]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0cm}{5mm}{2mm}[15mm]
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0cm}{2mm}{0cm}

% Parts, chapters and sections
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}% Prefix chapter with part number
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}\refstepcounter{part} #1}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\fontsize{18}{21,6}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{\fontsize{18}{21,6}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
    \part{}


    \chapter{\sloppy{Physikalisch/chemische Eigenschaften Eigenschaften Stabilität des kosmetischen Mittels}}

    \begin{raggedright}

        \chapter{Physikalisch/chemische Eigenschaften Eigenschaften Stabilität des kosmetischen Mittels}

    \end{raggedright}

    \begingroup
    \hyphenpenalty 10000
    \exhyphenpenalty 10000

    \chapter{Physikalisch/chemische Eigenschaften Eigenschaften Stabilität des kosmetischen Mittels}

    \endgroup

    \chapter{\mbox{Physikalisch/chemische} \mbox{Eigenschaften} \mbox{Eigenschaften} \mbox{Stabilität} \mbox{des} \mbox{kosmetischen} \mbox{Mittels}}

\end{document}
```

hyphenation is not wanted.
[image: hyphenation is not wanted.]

overflow outside of the boy is not wanted.
[image: overflow outside of the boy is not wanted.]

Comment: Use `\raggedright` or `\filright` inside `\titleformat`: `\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\fontsize{18}{21,6}\selectfont\bfseries\raggedright}...` See the `titlesec` documentation for details

Comment: Unrelated, but if you use the `memoir` class instead of `report` (also skip the `fancyhdr` stuff as `memoirs` own if better integrated), then ragged right  sectional headings is the default

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. This works perfectly!